# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded ERROR after I tried to use a selector tag in app component ANGULAR 4 & TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to follow The Heroes Tutorial in Angular, and while I'm integrating my BookListComponent in AppComponent, using the selector tag   in app.component.html, I observed the following error: (I'm using ANGULAR 4)

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Headers.append (headers.ts:93)
    at eval (headers.ts:59)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval (headers.ts:59)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at new Headers (headers.ts:59)
    at new BookService (book.service.ts:12)
    at createClass (provider.ts:362)
    at _createProviderInstance (provider.ts:326)
    at createProviderInstance (provider.ts:135)
```

The tutorial's code looks the same with mine, but I think that it's a configuration problem or something about providers list, I'm not sure.
There is someone here who had the same problem?
Here is my code:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'sdadas';
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BookComponent } from './book/book-details/book.component';
import { BookListComponent } from './book/book-list/book-list.component';
import { BookService } from './services/book.service';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BookComponent,
    BookListComponent
  ],
  providers: [ BookService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

book-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }from '@angular/router';

import { Book } from '../book-details/book';
import { BookService } from '../../services/book.service';

@Component({

  selector: 'book-list',
  templateUrl: './book-list.component.html'
})

export class BookListComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Library';
  books: Book[];
  selectedBook: Book;

  constructor(private bookService: BookService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getBooks();
  }

  getBooks(): void {
     this.bookService.getBooks()
      .then(books => {
        this.books = books
      });
  }

  onSelect(book: Book): void {
    this.selectedBook = book;
  }

}
```

book.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Book } from '../book/book-details/book';
import { BookComponent } from '../book/book-details/book.component';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class BookService {

    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    private bookUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/book';
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getBooks(): Promise<Book[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.bookUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as Book[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getBook(id: any): Promise <Book> {
        const url = `${this.bookUrl}/${id}`;
        console.log(url);
        return this.http.get(url)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as Book)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error) {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add `BookService` code?

Comment: I have edited the post with book.service.ts

Comment: @AndreeaDumitru why are you adding the book service again at the component level `providers: [BookService]` it should be at the root level only at app.module

Comment: I have tried to fix it, following the other similar posts and I have forgotten to delete after that, but it doesn't work anyway, after removing

Comment: How does your templates look like?

Comment: The book-list.component.html is empty and app.component.html has just a paragraph and a tag <book-list> </book-list>

Comment: @AndreeaDumitru I see no error in your code, and I tried it, and could not reproduce the issue. Seems there is something that is calling 'something' over and over, which is crashing your browser. Please try and reproduce the issue in a stackblitz and I'd be happy to take a look :)